# Multiple google maps iframe performance issues?

Tags: jquery, performance, google-maps

On my page I have 12 google maps, as you can guess this slows my page load time down dramatically as its making 12 seperate calls to load each map, Has anybody a solution to speed this up?

All I can think of is getting rid of the maps and using an image that links through to Google Maps itself only I don't really want to do that...

Comment: Is it loading the scripts or the actual rendering that slows down the load?

Answer (score 0):

You may initially use "empty" iframes(without a src-attribute) and assign the src to the iframes at `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()` .